# How many unordered N-seqences in M letter alphabet?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider alphabet 1 2 3 ... M
Consider unordered words of length N. How many of them ?

By unordered I mean we identify say words < 1 2> and <2 1>; < 1 2 2> <2 1 2> <2 2 1> and so on.

Is there closed simple formula ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can require that the letters be in alphabetical order.  Then you can use a [stars and bars argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to count them.  Add one letter of each sort so that you know there is at least one.  Now you have a word of $N+M$ letters and need to select $M-1$ places to make the breaks between letter types, so ${N+M-1 \choose M-1}$